# Compare attribute values through whole node-set

Tags: xml, xslt

I have xml data. And parse it using xslt transformation.
What I need is to find out if all child elements of particular element have same nested-element's values. Look:

if we have same values in :

```
<parent>
   <child>
      <compare>1</compare>
   </child>
   <child>
      <compare>1</compare>
   </child>
</parent>
```

we should copy all tree and set flag to "1":

```
<parent>
   ...
   </child>
   <flag>1</flag>
</parent>
```

If we have diffirent values:

```
<parent>
   <child>
      <compare>1</compare>
   </child>
   <child>
      <compare>2</compare>
   </child>
</parent>
```

we should copy all tree and set flag to "":

```
<parent>
   ...
   </child>
   <flag/>
</parent>
```

Comment: So am I right in saying you want to set the flag to 1 only if all the child nodes of the element contain identical nodes/values as each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="parent">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
            <flag>
                <xsl:variable name="comp" select="child[1]/compare"/>
                <!-- add flag value only if child/compare are the same -->
                <xsl:value-of select="child[1]/compare[
                    count(current()/child)
                    = 
                    count(current()/child[ compare=$comp ]
                    )]"/>
            </flag>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation, please?
Found that pretty interesting, but not obvoius.

Comment: Under a given "parent", if the count of "child" elements is equal to the count of "child" elements with same value of the first, then we have same value.

Answer (score 2):

How about comparing if anything is different from the first?

```
<xsl:template match="/parent">
  <parent>
    <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
    <flag>
      <xsl:if test="not(child[1]/compare != child/compare)">1</xsl:if>
    </flag>
  </parent>
</xsl:template>
```

this does mean if you only have one it will have a flag of 1

Comment: I think the `xsl:if` test is fine but I wonder why you use the verbose `<xsl:element name="flag>` to construct the element where a simple `<flag>` suffices.

Comment: Originally just clarity, but it was because I was writing it in a hurry, and I hacked something else. But you are right, I wouldn't normally use element - editing the answer to update with that.

Answer (score 1):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
       <flag><xsl:value-of select=
       "substring('1', 2 - not(child[compare != current()/child/compare]))"/></flag>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the following XML document:**

```
<parent>
   <child>
      <compare>1</compare>
   </child>
   <child>
      <compare>1</compare>
   </child>
</parent>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<parent>
   <child>
      <compare>1</compare>
   </child>
   <child>
      <compare>1</compare>
   </child>
   <flag>1</flag>
</parent>
```

**When the same transformation is applied on this XML document:**

```
<parent>
   <child>
      <compare>1</compare>
   </child>
   <child>
      <compare>2</compare>
   </child>
</parent>
```

**again the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<parent>
   <child>
      <compare>1</compare>
   </child>
   <child>
      <compare>2</compare>
   </child>
   <flag/>
</parent>
```

**Do note**:

1. Using and overriding the identity rule.
2. No explicit conditional instructions (or variables) are used at all.

Comment: @YegoshinMaxim: What do you mean by that?

Comment: for diffirent values flag should be reseted

Comment: @YegoshinMaxim: What's up with you man? I still don't understand what you are saying.

Comment: @YegoshinMaxim: OK, I got it -- fixed now.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but have already implemented the "accepted".

Comment: @YegoshinMaxim: You are welcome. An answer is even more important for its educational effect -- one doesn't need to "implement" it in order to learn from it. What one can learn from this answer is how to write a transformation in the simplest possible way -- short, no use of unnecessary constructs -- variables, conditionals or functions.